# Add Signature to Email in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

today I'm having the issue that I'm trying to add a signature to a email sent from my webapp, I'm using the System.Net.Mail.

PS: I don't know if this helps but I'm using the client to connect with Gmail and send the mails from a gmail account.

```
    public string Notify(   int iduser, int idcompany)
    {
        var us = new Users(iduser);
        var emp = new Company(idcompany);
        var super_user = new Users(emp.iduser);

        body = "The Company " + emp.Name + "Has sent their questions.\n Administrator: " + us.Login;
        name = us.Login;
        subject = "Send questions [" + emp.Comercial_Name + "] - " + us.Login;
        to.Add(super_user.Email);
        replyTo = us.Email;
        return Send();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean an actual hand-written signature or just some personalised signature text that is simply appended to the body of the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signatures are just part of the body of the e-mail so you can simply do:

```
body = body + signature;
```

where you have defined `signature` previously.

Though as you are concatenating a lot of strings here, using a `StringBuilder` would be more efficient.

Comment: And if it is an Image, I just set a variable with the path of the image?

Comment: @CarlosMora - What you have, plus my code will work for plain text e-mails. If you want to add images you'll have to change the format of the body to rich text or even HTML.